# Android toolbar doesn't expand when scrolling up

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I have a toolbar that collapses when the `RecyclerView` scrolls down, but when the user scrolls up quickly, the toolbar doesn't expand. Any idea what is wrong?

This behavior is shown in this video: https://youtu.be/67ntPkW-5XA

Layout code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="showText"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to expand every time you scroll up, you should add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to the view you want to be shown.

As I understand you want to add this to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Possible flags:

`scroll`: this flag should be set for all views that want to scroll off the screen - for views that do not use this flag, they’ll remain pinned to the top of the screen

`enterAlways`: this flag ensures that any downward scroll will cause this view to become visible, enabling the ‘quick return’ pattern

`enterAlwaysCollapsed`: When your view has declared a minHeight and you use this flag, your View will only enter at its minimum height (i.e., ‘collapsed’), only re-expanding to its full height when the scrolling view has reached it’s top.

`exitUntilCollapsed`: this flag causes the view to scroll off until it is ‘collapsed’ (its minHeight) before exiting